# Amazon S3 - does root user have access to buckets?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am testing S3 calls using DHC REST client in Chrome.  In these tests, the Authorization is all based on my root user credentials.

I can do a GET with //mybucket.s3.amazonws.com, and a list of the items in mybucket is returned.

If I add an item to retrieve (//mybucket.s3.amazonws.com/myitem), I always get 403 Forbidden.

I thought that the root user had automatic access to the objects, but am I wrong about that?

I took screen prints of both tests, which I'll supply if needed.

Answer (score 0):

After some further monkeying around, I found my answer.  Yes, the AWS root user can access individual items.  But the Authorization header string changes.  When you retrieve an object, that object's key participates in the calculation of the auth string.  Thus, the same string used to retrieve the bucket list does not work when retrieving an object.